# Eclipse Maven dependency doesn't find

Tags: eclipse, search, maven, dependency-management

I have add to pom.xml of my project repository:

```
        <repository>
        <id>java.net</id>
        <name>java.net</name>
        <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
    </repository>
```

But when I go to tab dependencies of pom - click add I don't see version jsf-impl 2.0 or more
[image: I don't see version 2.0]

How to fix it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't unless Maven can download the remote index to power the dependency search. Check the Maven console for log details.

Answer (score 3):

To fix search dependency search engine you have to "download repository index". To do so:

> Window -> Preferences -> Maven -> User Settings -> Update Settings

(even if this file does not exist!)

If you want to be up to date with this list I recommend enabling:

> Window -> Preferences -> Maven -> Download repository index updates on
>   startup

Answer (score 0):

Just add the dependency to the pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```