# Added Maven dependency, Eclipse doesn't see it

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2e

I add guava 17.0 to my pom.xml, Eclipse automatically rebuilds project.

Ran `mvn dependency:resolve`, maven shows `com.google.guava:guava:jar:17.0:compile` in the list of resolved files.

However when in Eclipse I try to auto-complete `com.google.g`, it says "No default proposals". I've added dependencies in my pom.xml before, run `mvn dependency:resolve` and Eclipse picked them up immediately. What's different this time?

I've tried the following so far:

- Tried cleaning the project and letting it automatically rebuild.
- Clean, auto-rebuild, re-start Eclipse.
- `mvn clean` followed by `mvn install`
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/6913992/91933
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/12978632/91933
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/2393810/91933 (although I couldn't get Eclipse to accept $HOME/.m2 as the Maven repository (which it is)).

I can see `target/<projname>-1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/lib/guava-17.0.jar`.

My configuration:

- OS: OS X 10.9.3
- Maven: 3.1.1
- Eclipse: Kepler (with m2e 1.4)

Comment: can you see that jar being added in eclipse managed classpath ?

Comment: try running the `mvn eclipse:clean` and then the `mvn eclipse:eclipse` command in a seperate command prompt and then refresh the project in eclipse. Most of the times, this works for me.

Comment: Don't use `mvn eclipse:eclipse` use the import of Eclipse and the rest is handled by `m2e` plugin of Eclipse.

Comment: @khmarbaise You're saying that I should run `mvn eclipse:clean`, remove the project from Eclipse and then re-import it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The suggestion by [@khmarbaise](https://stackoverflow.com/users/296328/khmarbaise) works best and solves all problems.

1. Just delete the project from Eclipse.
2. Re-import as "Existing Maven Projects" and point it towards the directory that contains the project's `pom.xml` file.
3. Let Eclipse's `m2e` plugin handle the rest

Worked flawlessly for me.

The following advice (taken from https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/webtoolsplatform#maven) may only apply to GAE projects, but seems like it should be generally applicable (my project is GAE, so can't be sure):

> The directory at the root of the Maven project must *not*
>   contain any of the following:
>
> ```
> 1. A subdirectory named target
>
> 2. A subdirectory named .settings
>
> 3. A file named .classpath
>
> 4. A file named .project
> ```

Comment: I have all of those folders in my Maven project root folder, yet I can use similar Maven dependencies like apache commons-lang without any problems. Is Guava different in some way?

Comment: Maybe this will help someone: The certificate to communicate with my organization's maven artifactory had expired; once I updated it everything worked.

Comment: @JamesDaily I think that advice is only for the first time when importing a maven project into Eclipse.

Comment: The root directory does need those files.

Comment: @markvgti Eclipse didn't like me removing .project!  Are you sure about this one?

Comment: Hi @PaulMorrison! Can't claim to be an Eclipse expert, but it worked for me. YMMV. Did you exit Eclipse before you did all this? The idea is that the `m2e` plugin will regenerate the project.

Comment: Thanks, @markvgti ! That's probably what happened to me!  I cleaned out the .m2\repository folder, and the project is now working!

Answer (score 1):

In file `pom.xml` inside `< dependency > seleneium` maybe you have defined `< scope> test`  e.g. `< scope>test < /scope>`.

Removing/deleting this also can solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

At first, remove projects as markvgti suggested. I did this three times without success.

My solution was deleting ".project" files and the ".settings" directory in the several projects. Last step was reimporting as "Maven Projects" in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the issue too where my WebDriver and chrome driver was not being recognized even after adding the selenium dependencies. Followed below steps  seeing the above comments.

And the issue got resolved. Thanks for the help.

1. Create a Maven project.
2. Add Maven dependencies(selenium and testng minimum)
3. Go to CMD to where your project is.
4. Run command mvn eclipse:clean
5. Then run command mvn eclipse:eclipse
6. Go to eclipse and refresh your project to apply the dependencies and then the jars are added to your project.